# FileNotFoundError: File b'/path/to/my/file.csv' does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, unicode

I'm facing a silly problem but I can figure out a solution.
I'm trying to open a .csv file thru:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/path/to/my/file.csv')
```

But I.m getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'/path/to/my/file.csv' does not exist
```

As you might have noticed the b is being added in the process, making the string a byte type instead of a string in this is causing all the trouble.
I tried to add the r', making it like:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/my/file.csv')
```

but I got the same error. How can I change this process in order to avoid the byte transformation and open the CSV file thru the path?

My OS is Ubuntu and im running on Python3.

Comment: Have you tried storing the filepath as an env var? Like: file_path = '/path/to/my/file.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(file_path)

Otherwise try with " " quotes. It may be interpreting string as literal.

Comment: Tried both, and a combination of both and it didn't work.

Comment: are you sure your path is correct? try full path to your file

Comment: have nothing with `b`, when cannot find file, all information will have this `b`. So this should be your file name issue. `os.path.exists` to see if your path has any issue.

Comment: Are you *sure* the path exists?  I get the same error message (with byte string) even on Windows, but I only get it if the path really doesn't exist.

Comment: It also looks like a bug in Pandas.  If I make a file with a non-ASCII filename but valid content like `'马克.csv'` or `pingüino.csv` it gets an `OSError`, but if it is a non-existent file the `FileNotFoundError` contains a UTF-8 encoded byte string of the filename.

Comment: Ok so I found a way to fix, first I change the file name and path and did the checked if the path existed and it work this time! Thanks